# Sql availability group listener not failing over

Tags: sql-server, sql

We have built two sql clusters with always on availability groups, based on the windows failover cluster service.

This is done as per Microsoft documented process, however we are getting some strange behaviour, in server manager on the primary node we see the servers being managed, the status of listener, failover cluster, primary and secondary mode as all showing online, however I cannot ping the cluster ip, ping is not blocked.

On node two the server manager shows primary and secondary nodes as online, the cluster and availability listener is not online, which seems ok as this is the secondary node.

The issue is when I failover the cluster goes from primary to secondary with no issues, but the listener doesn’t failover, even if it’s done through sql availability group management.

The cluster, the first node and second node all show online on the secondary node except the listener.

Completely baffled, is there anything I should be aware off, the cluster is built as per Microsoft instructions, not that they’ve helped much

All running sql 2016 sp1 on server 2012r2

Comment: From a Windows clustering perspective, are the listener and the AG in the same group? You can check this with powershell: `get-cluster «your cluster name» | get-clusterresource | format-list`. The listener will be listed as a "Network Name" ResourceType.

Comment: @BenThul hi Ben thanks for the reply, they are in the same group and everything is showing as online in the cluster, one thing I noticed is when I failover from the primary to secondary the cluster computer name cannot be accessed by the secondary node, and when I failover the ag from primary to secondary the primary cannot access the ag resource, all this is what is shown in server manager under all servers. I’m also getting a lot of dcom errors .. saying node1 can not connect to the ag through any dcom connections, and node2 cannot Access clustername with dcom on any known methods ..